# Connecting VM to outside world through a bridge

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, bridge

Currently setting up a VM (through AWS Firecracker, that shouldn't matter though, it just takes `tap0` and uses that for `eth0` in the guest) which should connect to the outside world. I've got the host connected to the internet through `eno1`, and I figured the simplest way to connect `tap0` to the router/internet would just be to bridge it to `eno2`, which I've also plugged into my router.

Currently I've got `br0` set up as the master of `eno2` and `tap0`. I've confirmed all three are `UP` when the VM is running. But from within the VM, there's no connection.

Host `ip link show`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:a8:42:37:bd:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f0
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:a8:42:37:bd:b3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f1
4: eno3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:a8:42:37:bd:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp3s0f0
5: eno4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:a8:42:37:bd:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp3s0f1
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether 02:42:b0:9e:8a:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
29: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:fc:4a:0d:d1:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
30: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:70:91:24:35:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Host `bridge link`:

```
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 5
30: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100
```

Guest `ip link show`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:fc:ff:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I don't think it's connected right at layer 2, since `ip route show` shows nothing, it stays stuck on `Raise network interfaces...` for ages when booting up, and despite my `/etc/network/interfaces` being set up right as far as I can tell, there's no IP address for `eth0`. Here's my `/etc/network/interfaces` if it helps:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I'm pretty bad at networking, so I might be doing something really wrong, and my assumption that going through `eno2` instead of `eno1` with everything else might be wrong. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Do I need to assign an IP address to the bridge, maybe? I'd assumed that the guest would get an IP and everything in between would just be transparent, but I see people talking about assigning IP addresses to bridges?

Comment: Does DHCP work on the host for eno2 (when not enslaved to br0) and br0 (when eno2 is enslaved to it)? (It is not necessary for br0 to have an IP btw.)

Comment: Have you perhaps configured ebtables or an nftables bridge table?

Comment: @TomYan I don't have any ebtables or nftables, I know that for sure

Comment: @TomYan Trying `dhclient eno2` gave me `grep: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*: No such file or directory` six times then dropped my SSH connections...